# Faster implementation python3 -leetcode problem set-

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I am new to problem sets, although the lines of code is so short but after submission it says that it's bit slow.

is it because of max or append ?
what to avoid in python to make things faster ?

```
class Solution:
    def kidsWithCandies(self, candies: List[int], extraCandies: int) -> List[bool]:
        greatestCandy = []
        for c in candies:
            greatestCandy.append((c + extraCandies) >= max(candies))
        return greatestCandy
```

The problem to solve here is to store bool in a list depending on the corresponding condition ->> if the number would be the greatest if added to extraCandies variable.

INPUT

```
[4,2,1,1,2]
 1
```

OUTPUT

```
[true,false,false,false,false]
```

Comment: "lines of code is so short" just an FYI in case you didn't already know but code length isn't necessarily correlated with speed.

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and expected output?

Comment: any advice of how to make it faster ? in general

Comment: `max(candies)` is quite expensive to calculate. Since `candies` never changes, you should call `max(candies)` once before the loop then save the result in a variable.

Comment: that reduced the time by 10 ms THANK YOU i did not know max is this expensive

Comment: @flask Any operation that needs to iterate an entire list should limited. It's just a matter of thinking about what work a function needs to do to do its job. It isn't possible to find the max number of an unsorted list without iterating the entire list.